# jQuery onLoad x jQuery onDomready

Tags: javascript, jquery

Toda vez que vou usar o [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) vejo as opções para inicializar o conteúdo do jQuery via `onLoad` ou `onDomready`.

Testei com a maior parte dos scripts que eu escrevo e não houve diferença funcional alguma. Pesquisando no Google vi que uma das principais diferenças é que via `onLoad` os scripts só começam a ser executados após todos os elementos serem carregados e isso inclui arquivos CSS, JS, imagens e etc., o que pode ser útil caso você precise carregar arquivos [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) em determinada ordem, mas em algum dado momento um destes arquivos faz referência a um outro que ainda não foi carregado, enquanto via `onDomready` uma vez carregado o conteúdo HTML da página os scripts começam a ser carregados já sem que necessariamente os demais tenham sido.

- Entendi correto essa diferença?
- Existe mais alguma  diferença a ser estudada e percebida?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isto que você disse está meio confuso:

> caso você precise carregar arquivos JS em determinada ordem, mas em algum dado momento um destes arquivos faz referência a um outro que ainda não foi carregado, enquanto via onDomready uma vez carregado o conteúdo HTML da página os scripts começam a ser carregados já sem que necessariamente os demais tenham sido.

Os arquivos JavaScript são por padrão carregados e executados na ordem em que se encontram no código-fonte do HTML, um após o outro (nunca em paralelo) – salvo algumas exceções*.

Se todos os seus scripts são carregados dessa forma, não importa se o código dentro deles posterga a execução de algo para o `DOMContentLoaded` ou para o `window.onload`. O resultado em ambos os casos será o mesmo: o código postergado será executado após todos os outros scripts terem sido carregados, e seus códigos executados (exceto esses códigos postergados).

---

As exceções que mencionei:

- Scripts em tags `<script>` que usam o atributo [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-async) são carregados de maneira assíncrona, e executados assim que carregados (em browsers com suporte a esse atributo).
- Scripts em tags `<script>` que usam o atributo [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer) são carregados de maneira assíncrona, e executados somente após o *parsing* do documento completo (em browsers com suporte a esse atributo). Isto equivale a executar código logo antes do evento `DOMContentLoaded`.
- Scripts injetados via `document.createElement()` + `document.body.appendChild` são carregados de maneira assíncrona, e executados assim que carregados.

Comment: Primeiramente desculpe a demora em responder, tem sido uma semana estressante com a implantação em produção de um sistema. Eu sei que os arquivos JS são carregados sequencialmente, o que eu quis dizer foi que em determinadas situações você é obrigado a determinar essa ordem, por exemplo, bibliotecas que usam jQuery precisam ser carregadas após o próprio jQuery para que funcionem, foi isso que quis dizer. Estudarei suas exceções, pois não conhecia a primeira e a terceira. A segunda por ser mais antiga foi até a solução que usei para resolver um determinado problema [continua]

Comment: Descrito na questão "[How to override your own jQuery's validate method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20380262/how-to-override-your-own-jquerys-validate-method)". Vale a pena ler o chat para ver uma outra solução que cheguei também.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi Ainda não sei se entendi, mas se quiser carregar tudo de maneira assíncrona e determinar a ordem das dependências, eu recomendo o require.js.

Comment: Um exemplo prático: qualquer plugin jQuery, se você o listar na lista de scripts antes do próprio jQuery vai dar problema, certo? Vou procurar esse require.js

Answer (score 3):

Essa é a maior diferença entre os dois eventos. Com `DOMContentLoaded`, os scripts começam a sua execução assim que o DOM (o HTML da página) está pronto para ser acedido pelo JavaScript.
Por outro lado, com `window.onload` o script espera que todo o conteúdo esteja carregado (incluindo imagens, CSS, etc., como denotou na pergunta).

Talvez a diferença mais relevante que não foi apontada seja a compatibilidade. O `window.onload` é suportado por browsers antigos, enquanto que o outro evento pode não ser, tanto quanto sei.

Comment: Outra diferença é que com jQuery.onLoad pode haver problemas com imagens cacheadas no IE.

Comment: Postei essa pergunta no SO também e um usuário me mostrou esse [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c58a6/). Basicamente, você pode ter diversos onDomready, enquanto onLoad apenas uma vez.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi É uma diferença interessante. Obrigado pela partilha!

Comment: Na verdade você pode ter diversos onLoad, se você continuar lendo ele mostra isso, mas nada que esteja atrelado a um onLoad que já foi carregado, meio confuso o negócio.