# Qual a melhor forma de fazer o carregamento de JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estava enfrentando problemas com o carregamento de JS, principalmente pelo IE8, e me surgiu essa dúvida. Pesquisei bastante, acabei melhorando algumas coisas.

Atualmente, eu carrego todos os arquivos JS no final da página, antes da tag `body`.

```
<body>
    ...
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="funcoes.js"></script>
</body>
```

No caso o `funcoes.js` é onde eu chamo (ou gostaria de chamar) todas as funções do site.
E é aí que acontecem os problemas.
Tenho nele por exemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    validar();
});

$(window).scroll(function () {
    ...
});

$("#form_contato").validate();

$('.bxslider').bxSlider();

function validar(){
    ...
}
```

Eu não sei se possui alguma ordem na chamada dessas funções...
Não sei, por exemplo, quando tenho que utilizar `$(function(){...});`.

Tenho sempre que ficar testando, e às vezes acontece de no IE8 alguma função não funcionar, daí começa a novela de mudar de lugar (as vezes chamando logo abaixo dos scripts no `body` entre as tags `script` resolve), daí essa função funciona, mas outra pára de funcionar, e daí lá vou eu começar a fazer testes de novo...

O que posso estar fazendo de errado?

Comment: Talvez essa [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1109/onde-devo-colocar-um-codigo-javascript-em-um-documento-html) ajude. Não fala especificamente do ie8

Comment: Sempre colocar precedência no carregamento do `js`, seguindo os itens mais acima que são exigidos logo após ... Pelas 3 referencias de `js` do seu exemplo não ta errado fazer assim,  mas, possa ser que você ta chamando item que ainda não foi declarado. Exemplo: tem ai no seu código bxSlider, cade a referencia do mesmo ??? Só lembrando que isso independe de navegador, se faltar o `js`, vai acontecer erros  ...

Comment: Esta pergunta também deve ajudar: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8416/jquery-onload-x-jquery-ondomready

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você precisa usar um framework que gerencia os requests de arquivos para você e faz isso apenas sob demanda, por exemplo, o arquivo com o método `validar()` vai ser carregado apenas se o método for chamado de fato, assim sempre fazendo request dos arquivos na ordem correta.

Pesquise sobre RequireJS:
http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score 4):

Os navegadores quando carregam uma página executam ela de cima pra baixo da direita para a esquerda. Quando o navegador passar por um arquivo javascript ele executa imediatamente o codigo deste mas no entanto se as funções do Javascript **estiverem fazendo uso do HTML antes do navegador chegar e escreve-lo dá erro**.

Para nossa felicidade o navegador dispara dois eventos:

**Primeiro -**  Nos indica quando uma pagina carregou todo o HTML (**DOM Ready**)

**Segundo -** Nos indica quando uma pagina carregou todas as imagens. (**Window Load**)

Quando você usa funções que lidam com o HTML, o ideal é chamá-las somente quando todo o HTML ja estiver carregado **DOM Ready**

No caso do JQuery você deveria começar sempre a execução do seu Javascript no:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     Funcao1();
     Funcao2();
     Funcao3();
     //... etc
});

function Funcao1() {}
function Funcao2() {}
function Funcao3() {}
```

Answer (score -5):

Carregue as bibliotecas entre `<head> e </head>`. O conteúdo do head é carregado antes do body.

Comment: Nem sempre, muitos códigos javascript precisam que o DOM esteja pronto para serem executados, nesses casos é preferível carregar logo antes de `</body>`